# Who is watching the watchdog?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, catch-phrases

I am looking for an expression that conveys the meaning *Who is watching the watchdog*?

Comment: 'Who watches the watchers?' has vastly more Googlecred than mplungjan's variant or the one I like, 'Who watches those who watch us?' I think Star Trek is to blame.

Comment: "Who watches the watchers" or "who watches the watchmen" is so ubiquitous I am surprised you had to bring up dogs at all. There's even a Wikipedia article. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quis_custodiet_ipsos_custodes%3F

Comment: Right. I knew the other one now you mention it :) Even in Latin. slipped my mind there...

Comment: _Quis custodiet ipsos custodes?_ 'Who is to guard those (self-)same guards?_ The subjunctive _custodiet_ makes the problem clear, and the intensive _ipsos_ makes it obvious that the same bunch of "guards" are involved on both ends of the "guarding". You can say a lot with a few words in an inflected language.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I believe that is definitive enough to be an answer, not simply a comment.

Comment: OK, if you say so. Give it a badge or something. But Hugo has already posted it below.

Answer (score 3):

A similar common phrase already exists, **"who watches the watchers?"** or **"who watches the
watchmen?"**.

This is from the Latin [*quis custodiet ipsos custodes?*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quis_custodiet_ipsos_custodes%3F).

Comment: `sed -e 's/^/sed /`:)